# How to get expandable items in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

I want to display recyclerview with sub items which needs to expand/collapse.

For example,

Main Item 1 (expand)

--- Child Item 1 (expand)
------- sub Item 1
------- sub Item 2

--- Child Item 2 (expand)
------- sub Item 1

Main Item 2 (expand)

--- Child Item 1 (expand)
------- sub Item 1
------- sub Item 2

--- Child Item 2
--- Child Item 3

Main Item 3
Main Item 4

When I click on mainitem it needs to show child items and when I click on child item 1 it needs to expand and display sub items.

How to do this in Android recyclerview..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of recyclerview , you can use expandable recyclerview

```
compile 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.4'
```

For more info you can refer to :
https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

**Edit**:
To create your own custom expandable recycler view,  you can use  `ConcatAdapter` to achive this.
Refer to this article for more details:
https://medium.com/codeshake/create-an-expandable-recyclerview-with-the-mergeadapter-254fd671fa5b

Comment: Without using third party library need to implement this..

Comment: You can refer to this article on how to create your own expandable recycler view [link](https://medium.com/codeshake/create-an-expandable-recyclerview-with-the-mergeadapter-254fd671fa5b)

Answer (score 0):

[ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView) is the best option i can think of right now.

Please note, that it's NOT based on `RecyclerView`, but on `ListView`, but that should only matter if you have tons of items